# communicate between file and subprocess

Tags: python

I have a text file(.txt file) which have a set of commands and this file has to be stdin to a subprocess and the commands from the file should be fed into the subprocess program.

the part of the full code is as follows:

```
    def startmedina(self):
        self.process=subprocess.Popen(['pre xx'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        return
    def quitmedina(self):
        os.killpg(self.process.pid,signal.SIGKILL)
        return
    def medprocess(self):
        f=open('/net/s019fc000110ge/mnt_home/vol/home6/vnandak/Python_scripts/new_protcheck.txt','r')
        try:
            self.process.stdin = f.read()
            self.process.stdout
```

the function "startmedina" starts the desired "medina" program and then it should take the commands from the stdin and it should process the commands. basically the medina program can talk to python script through pipes but i don't know how to do this.

can any one help me witht his

Answer (score 0):

Use [communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
self.process.communicate(f.read())
```

Comment: i used it the program is not responding, it froze @rczajka